# Why does Wubi.exe for Ubuntu 11.10 not run on Windows 7 64bit?

Tags: wubi

I installed an older version of Ubuntu before with the Wubi installer. I then did an upgrade of the Ubuntu to the latest 11.10 version but this did not work well. Icons were missing in Ubuntu and it was pretty messed up (with no option to shut down Ubuntu etc.). I therefore completely uninstalled ubuntu from within Windows 7 64 bit and downloaded the new Ubuntu 11.10 Wubi.exe. When I now execute the Wubi.exe I get the normal Win7 "User Account Control" notification asking if I want to allow the program to make changes to my computer. I answer with "yes" and now the installer should start. But it doesn't! I just get a quick change of the mouse pointer showing that something happened but then nothing. As if I never tried to execute the wubi.exe. No error messages no nothing. I abviously tried this in all compatibility flavours and as administrator. Always the same thing. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Try cleaning out your `%temp%` directory - remove `py??.tmp` directories and any `py??.tmp.exe` files from there: see [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1619878) for reference.

If you have Python installed on Windows, then there is a different solution, that involves modifying your `%PYTHONPATH%` environment variable. Here is an [old bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/365501) on this.

You should also check for a log file - if the problem is python then there's likely no log file, otherwise you'll find a log file in the `%temp%` directory called `wubi-11.10-revxxx.log` that might provide an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I lived interesting problem for that issue.

I found log files and my wubi.exe is located on C:/ drive but log files say wubi try to opening game.iso files that it is located on D:/.

When I move the file any location from D:/ it worked very well.