# Why Won't WUBI Start On Windows XP (32-Bit)

Tags: wubi

I try to start up wubi.exe and nothing ever appears on the screen, I even have TaskManager open and the program just quits after a minute (not even). Is this a Windows XP 32-Bit glitch or error?

Comment: See if this helps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/89027/why-does-wubi-exe-for-ubuntu-11-10-not-run-on-windows-7-64bit (the logfile will be wubi-12.04-rev266.log instead of the one mentioned in that post). If it doesn't help, post back details on what you've tried and what happened.

Answer (score 2):

Move the Wubi.exe in the same folder in which the Ubuntu .iso file is.
 Also make sure that you don't have any other .iso archives in that folder.